# Rest Authorization with OAuth?

Tags: rest, oauth

When I am reading about REST and session management/authorization a lot people suggest OAuth. For me it is a conflictive thought, because I thought OAuth is just for giving third parties authorization about something. So why use it for my own client to access my rest service? Do I think wrong about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right. If it's your own client so the client is trusted by the service, OAuth isn't required, you can use other approach between your client and service to authenticate/authorize.